# ¿En WPF existe una forma de rendeizar una ventana con base a ciertas condiciones?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, wpf

Estoy realizando una aplicación de escritor en .net con c# y me encuentro en la situación de solicitar un password si la aplicación se configura a modo sin conexión y pedir un usuario y contraseña cuando este en linea.
Mi duda es si existe algo parecido como en vuejs para mostrar ciertos elementos con base a una condición, o si acaso debo manejas dos ventanas diferentes, una para cada caso

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Para entender mejor tu pregunta, por favor revisa la página [ask] (y de paso, ¡obtienes tu primera medalla!). Incluye el código de lo que has intentado o por lo menos de qué sección intentas hacer.

Comment: Claro que se puede, pero qué cosas quieres cambiar? sé más específico, quieres cambiar el color de fondo? los botones? el texto?